# hash inside liste of hash extracted from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have a simple array

```
arr = ["Japan", "Egypt", "Spain", "Brazil",....]
```

I want to extract each element and make it a hash

```
japan = Hash.new("Japan")

egypt = Hash.new("Egypt")

brazil = Hash.new("Brazil")
```

finally store all of the hash inside a groupping  hash

```
country = {"Japan" => 0, "Egypt" => 0,"Brazil" => 0,.....}
```

Comment: Can you show example of what do you have at the beginning and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: that's an example , I have only arr at the beginning and finally i have Country

Comment: Do you want to convert each element into a separate hash or do you want to create a single hash containing all elements?

Comment: I want to create to create a hash containing all elements

Comment: If the initial array is `arr = ["Japan", "Egypt", "Japan"]`, What is the expected output ?

Comment: country = {"Japan" => 0, "Egypt" => 0,"Brazil" => 0,.....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but you can try the following:

```
arr = ["Japan", "Egypt", "Spain", "Brazil"]
arr.each { |a| Object.const_set(a, Hash.new(a)) } #initialize hashes
```

---

```
Country = arr.map {|a| [a, 0]}.to_h
#=> {"Japan"=>0, "Egypt"=>0, "Spain"=>0, "Brazil"=>0}
```

or

```
Country = Hash[arr.map {|a| [a, 0]}]
#=> {"Japan"=>0, "Egypt"=>0, "Spain"=>0, "Brazil"=>0}
```

*Note: Ruby variables should be in lowercase like `japan` and `egypt` and constants in uppercase like `JAPAN` and `EGYPT`*.

Comment: thanks for your response, the problem is at the end i want to have Country as a hash and contain a list of hash not simple element so japon is a hash, egypt is  hash and all of them are stored in Country

Comment: @BriniH can you post the expected hash ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
country = {}
arr.each do |name|
  country[name] = 0
end
```

Comment: `Country = arr.each_with_object({}) { |name, memo| memo[name] = 0 }`. Your code redefines a constant, that leads to MRI warning and is in general not appreciated.

Comment: @mudasobwa it doesn't redefine the constant.

Comment: @Stefan oh, indeed, my bad :(

Comment: You shouldn't use `Country` as the name of a variable. Use `country` instead. Constants start with capital letters. Also, there are better, more idiomatic, ways to accomplish what you're doing such as simply doing `country = Hash.new(0)` then moving on to using `country`.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the result you specified as requested output:

```
countries = ["Japan", "Egypt", "Spain", "Brazil"]
countries_hash = countries.zip([0] * countries.size).to_h
#⇒ {"Japan"=>0, "Egypt"=>0, "Spain"=>0, "Brazil"=>0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `reduce` would help:

```
arr = ["Japan", "Egypt", "Spain", "Brazil",....]
arr.reduce({}) do |hash, element|
  hash[element] = 0
  hash
end
```

Comment: Look into using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object). It's similar to `reduce`/`inject` but doesn't require returning the container at the end of the block so it's a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious:

```
countries.map { |country| [country, 0] }.to_h
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the most obvious, since `countries` is not defined in your code or the OP's, so your example doesn't work.

Comment: @theTinMan, indeed. In fact it is so obvious that everyone that has the context of the question can see that it is obvious, even if it doesn't directly work. You can't get more obvious than that! (: